# Proper data objects for reproducible scraping: storing XML document (a list) along results in a dataframe

Tags: r, xml, list, dataframe, dplyr

I'm scraping pages from a Yelp-style website. I'd like to loop through each business and scrape the contents of the business page, identifying key characteristics such as name, address, etc., but in case I'd like to re-run the scrape later, I'd like to also save the entire XML document (parsed with rvest::read_html).

For the sake of usability, I'd like to store all this in a dataframe. I would like one column to be the store URL, another the XML document (this is a list of lists), and a third "details" that I have scraped from the XML document (this is also a list of lists, since a scrape term does not always return items of consistent length).

An example of code used to create this data object is below.

```
stores <- data.frame(url=as.character(store_urls), html=NA,  details=NA)

for(i in 1:nrow(stores)) {

# All pages have some HTML info on top; details has more store info below too.
html_page <- read_html(paste0(stores$url[i], "/#/details"))

# Make an empty list that you'll fill with data.
details <- list()
details$name <- html_page %>% html_nodes(".listing-subtitle") %>% 
html_text() %>% extract(1)
details$address <- html_page %>% html_nodes("[itemprop=streetAddress]") %>% 
html_text()

# Save both lists to the dataframe.
stores$html[i] <- list(html_page); rm(html_page)
stores$details[i] <- list(details); rm(details)
}
```

On this dataframe, column-wise operations e.g., `table(stores$url)` work just fine. But operations that work on the whole dataframe, e.g., those in dplyr, throw the following error:

```
Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : 
first argument must be atomic
```

I think this is occurring because my dataframe is a list of lists, rather than a non-list vector of lists. And this makes sense, as in R, non-list vectors by design cannot hold lists. So, is there some way around this problem for me, such that I can store two lists as columns in a dataframe without breaking the dataframe functions? If not, what would be the advisable way to store this data, given the need to reproduce results and the inconsistent nature of scraped data?

Comment: Can you `str(stores)` to confirm whether the data.frame was coerced to a list? `dplyr` is really meant for tidy tables.  `purr` may be a better option for list operations.

Answer (score 1):

You should use dplyr::data_frame (*aka* tibble). data_frame prints nicely any kind of R object.

Your code could look like this (no `store_urls` available!):

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

stores <- data_frame(url = as.character(store_urls))
stores <- mutate(stores, html_page = read_html(paste0(url, "/#/details")))

get_name_and_addr <- function(x) {
  name <- html_nodes(x, ".listing-subtitle") %>% 
    html_text() %>% extract(1)
  address <- html_nodes(x, "[itemprop=streetAddress]") %>% 
    html_text()
  data_frame(name, address)
}

stores <- mutate(stores, details = map(html_page, get_name_and_addr))
stores
```